# How to perform database synchronization in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on web application and desktop based application both databases are same but on different server.
One is on live server and another is in local pc.

Now i want to synchronize both database after synchronization both database must have to same.

Is there any way to do that kind of synchronization in sql server?

Every solution will be highly appriciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is no - there is no way to do that in sql server. There are products for that, but product recommendations are not welcome here.

Comment: Hint: MS publishes a framework for that. Sync framework. It will require coding, but any solution will. It sadly looks abandoned.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint , it will be very helpful to me, I have prepared demo with Sync framework from one table , It works perfect , Is it possible to do that with more than 300 tables dynamically??

Comment: Seriously - no idea. It is not something I am working with. Never did. This type of sync is quite rarely needed.

Comment: Hi, Yes i got my answer i can sync tables dynamically, you saved my working hours thanks a lot for hint

Answer (score 1):

SymmetricDS supports multi-master replication of SQL Server. If the two databases are identical, the configuration should be small. This solution does not require any code.

There is an example that comes with it that should do everything that you need.

The free open source version can be found at [SymmetricDS.org](http://symmetricds.org)